# calling javascript function from html button in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

So i created a chrome extension where a popup appears when you click the extension. There is a button that when clicked should open a website in a new tab. i cant seem to get the tab to open when i click the button. ive tried just using html and java script but nothing works. i inspected the popup and i dont have any errors. if anyone could help id appreciate it.

**popup.js**

```
var myBtn=document.getElementById('myButton');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
window.location.href='my link'
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: darkblue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 50px;

      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
      }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="my button" />
<script src="popup.js">  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assigning to `window.location.href` doesn't open a new tab, it replaces the current tab.

Comment: Use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) to open a new tab, instead of `window.location.href`